# Can apps created using Quickly for Ubuntu be used in Windows or Mac?

Tags: application-development, quickly, html, css, crossplatform

Like the topic or how to develop cross platform application based on html and css with system files dealing?

I used to use wxpython, but after several web development projects it scares me. I love html and css way of build UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily, Quickly apps use a lot of things that are unique to Linux desktops to make your app run and integrate better.

Comment: how about this part "how to develop cross platform application based on html and css with system files dealing?"